# Where can I learn more about these two functions obtained from IFF and XOR?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, boolean-algebra, propositional-calculus

Given a set $X$, write $\mathrm{heaps}(X)$ for the set of all **finite** heaps (or 'multisets', if you prefer) on $X$.

Under this definition, it is well-known that if a binary operation $*$ on a set $X$ is

1. commutative
2. associative
3. and has an identity

then this operation gives rise to a function $\Phi : \mathrm{heaps}(X) \rightarrow X$ in a natural way.

For example, the operation $+$ on the real numbers gives rise to the function $\sum,$ defined on finite heaps of real numbers. Similarly, $\times$ gives rise to $\prod,$ etc.

In particular, if we write $\uplus$ for the heapic sum, then $\Phi$ can be characterized as the unique function satisfying $$\Phi(H \uplus I) = \Phi(H) * \Phi(I)$$ for all $H,I \in \mathrm{heaps}(X).$

Now let $X =$ the Boolean domain, which we will denote $\mathbb{B}.$

It is a surprising fact that the operators IFF (denoted $\leftrightarrow$) and XOR (denoted $\not\leftrightarrow$) satisfy conditions 1,2 and 3, at least in classical logic. In particular, they're associative, which I don't find at all intuitive.

Anyway, it follows that $\leftrightarrow$ and $\not \leftrightarrow$ each yield a function $\mathrm{heaps}(\mathbb{B}) \rightarrow \mathbb{B}.$

I'm interested in these functions from both a logical, and an algebraic point of view.

**Where can I learn more?**

---

*Discussion.* Lets denote them as follows.

1. The function obtained from $\leftrightarrow,$ lets denote $\mathrm{ef}.$
2. The function obtained from $\not\leftrightarrow,$ lets denote $\mathrm{ot}.$

These names are motivated as follows. For $H \in \mathrm{heaps}(\mathbb{B}),$ we have that $\mathrm{ef}(H)$ is true iff an even number of elements of $H$ are false; similarly, $\mathrm{ot}(H)$ is true iff an odd number of elements of $H$ are true.

Anyway, the functions $\mathrm{ef}$ and $\mathrm{ot}$ have some seriously neat properties.

Here's what I've got so far.

Firstly, we can negate pairs without changing anything. $$\mathrm{ef}(H \uplus \{x,y\}) = \mathrm{ef}(H \uplus \{\neg x, \neg y\}),\;\; \mathrm{ot}(H \uplus \{x,y\}) = \mathrm{ot}(H \uplus \{\neg x, \neg y\})$$

Secondly, negation passes straight through uninhibited.

$$\mathrm{ef}(H \uplus \{\neg x\}) = \neg\mathrm{ef}(H \uplus \{ x\}),\;\; \mathrm{ot}(H \uplus \{\neg x\}) = \neg\mathrm{ot}(H \uplus \{ x\})$$

Thirdly, repeated variables annihilate as follows.

$$\mathrm{ef}(H \uplus \{x,x\}) = \mathrm{ef}(H),\;\; \mathrm{ot}(H \uplus \{x,x\}) = \mathrm{ot}(H)$$

Fourthly, $$\mathrm{ef}(\emptyset) = \top,\;\; \mathrm{ot}(\emptyset) = \bot$$

Fifthly, they're equal precisely when the cardinality of $H$ is odd.

$$|H| \;\mathrm{odd} \implies \mathrm{ef}(H) = \mathrm{ot}(H)$$
$$|H| \;\mathrm{even} \implies \mathrm{ef}(H) \neq \mathrm{ot}(H)$$

Sixthly, they interact nicely.

$$\mathrm{ef}(H \uplus \mathrm{ot}(I)) = \mathrm{ot}(\mathrm{ef}(H) \uplus I)$$

Seventhly, we can split into cases as follows.

$$\mathrm{ef}(H \uplus I) = [\mathrm{ef}(H) \wedge \mathrm{ef}(I)] \vee [\neg\mathrm{ot}(H) \wedge \neg\mathrm{ot}(I)]$$

$$\mathrm{ot}(H \uplus I) = [\mathrm{ot}(H) \wedge \neg\mathrm{ef}(I)] \vee [\neg\mathrm{ef}(H) \wedge \mathrm{ot}(I)]$$

Dualising the above expressions:

$$\mathrm{ot}(H \uplus I) = [\mathrm{ot}(H) \vee \mathrm{ot}(I)] \wedge [\neg\mathrm{ef}(H) \vee \neg\mathrm{ef}(I)]$$

$$\mathrm{ef}(H \uplus I) = [\mathrm{ef}(H) \vee \neg\mathrm{ot}(I)] \wedge [\neg\mathrm{ot}(H) \vee \mathrm{ef}(I)]$$

Comment: Comment: what you call $\text{heaps}$ (which I wouldn't call by this name because it is already taken; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(mathematics) ) is the monad associated to the adjunction between sets and commutative monoids (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(category_theory) ). It is a variation of what is in computer science called the list monad.

Comment: On what concerns the mentioned 'non-intuitive' _classical_ associativity of $\leftrightarrow$, it might be interesting to notice that the _intuitionistic_ IFF (or its negation) is indeed **not** associative.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, thanks for the info. Those Monad's in particular look very interesting - closure operators have always been pretty much my favourite concept. Regarding terminology, I use "heap" because I find "bag" vulgar, and because "subheap" is preferable to "submultiset." But if anyone knows of better alternative, I'll gladly change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Algebraically, XOR is more usually viewed as the addition in $\mathbb Z_2$ (where 0 corresponds to false and 1 to true), which accounts for many of its nice properties -- in particular for the fact that it's associative. In this role it is often notated $\oplus$, so the multiset extension would be $\bigoplus$.

The *multiplication* in $\mathbb Z_2$ is just $\land$ under the same identification, so algebra and logic align nicely here. (In fact we can recover the entire logical structure from the ring operations since $A\lor B = A \oplus B \oplus (A\land B)$ and $\neg A=1\oplus B$ -- this provides the correspondence between a Boolean algebra and a Boolean ring, which is any ring in which $x^2=x$ for all $x$).

IFF is simply the De Morgan dual of $\oplus$, so it is associative (etc) as well. Alternatively we can write $(A\leftrightarrow B)=A\oplus B\oplus 1$, so by associativity and commutativity,
$$ a_1 \leftrightarrow a_2 \leftrightarrow \cdots \leftrightarrow a_n =
a_1 \oplus a_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus a_n \oplus \underbrace{1\oplus\cdots\oplus1}_{n-1\text{ ones}}$$
where the underbraced part is either $0$ or $1$ according to whether $n$ is odd or even.

The fact that negation "passes through" these operators can be explained by the fact that $\neg A = 1\oplus A$, and the "lifting" of negations out of $\oplus$ is then just associativity. Since $1\oplus 1=0$, an even number of negations cancel each other out.

Comment: Thanks. If there's anywhere good for learning more about $\mathbb{Z}_2$, please indicate tell. The problem is that for $n \geq 3$, the groups in the family $\mathbb{Z}_{n \geq 3}$ lack most of the structure that makes $\mathbb{Z}_2$ interesting; in particular, I don't think there's anything like negation for the groups in $\mathbb{Z}_{n \geq 3}.$

Comment: Also, I really like the way you explained the connection between $\leftrightarrow$ and $\oplus$. I sort of new it already, but the way its written in your answer is just crystal clear.

Comment: @user18921: I'm not aware offhand of any source dedicated to $\mathbb Z_2$. Most of the "interesting" structure you speak about is probably a feature of the ring having characteristic 2 (which means that addition and subtraction are the same operation), or possibly of being a Boolean ring (which implies characteristic 2). You definitely want to study some _ring theory_ here (the group structure is not enough to express all the interesting facts). Most abstract algebra textbooks should give it (though mixed with lots of other suff).

Comment: Cryptography and (in particular) coding theory make heavy use of higher algebra with $\mathbb Z_2$ as the base field, so it is possible that a text in one of these areas would contain a succinct overview of it. I don't have any titles to name, though.